# Selenium JavaScript - scroll element into view without overlapping with header

Tags: javascript, selenium

```
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

This scrolls the element into view but it goes behind the header on the page.

How can I scroll element into view so that the element is right below the header instead of behind the header?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method `scrollIntoView` can scroll the element at the top or at the bottom of the view with the default being at the top:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

So you could scroll it at the bottom instead:

```js
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", element);
```

You could also scroll it at the top and then by a 1/4th of the height of the view:

```js
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 4);", element);
```

Or just below your fixed header:

```js
webdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -arguments[1].offsetHeight);", element, header);
```

Comment: This is the best answer for scrolling in Chrome and Firefox, because the Action class does not work in Firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to focus on the specific element try the following:

```
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element =(WebElement)js.executeScript("document.querySelector('#urID').focus()");
```

- You need to change #urID to proper CSS locator.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this "**scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()**". hopefully it will automatically handle the position. i am trying in Salesforce Site. it is working fine

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();", element)
```

> *Notes : In Mozilla it is not supported. if you will work on Chrome and Edge then it might work fine.